# I'm having trouble captruing values within a for loop using selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm building a web scraper and I'm able to print all he data I need, but I'm struggling adding the data to my csv file, I feel like I need to add another for loop or even a function. Currently I'm able to get it to print one row of scraped data values, but it skips the 64 other rows of data values.

So far I've tried to put in another for loop and break up each variable into it's own function, but it just breaks my code, Here's what I have so far, I feel like I'm just missing something too.

```
#Gets listing box
    listingBox = searchGrid.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'v2-listing-card')

    #Loops through each listing box
    for listingBoxes in listingBox:

        listingUrl = []

        listingImg = []

        listingTitle = []

        listingPrice = []

        #Gets listing url
        listingUrl = listingBoxes.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.listing-link')
        print("LISTING URL:", listingUrl.get_attribute('href'))

        #Gets listing image
        listingImg = listingBoxes.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'img.wt-position-absolute')
        print("IMAGE:", listingImg.get_attribute('src'))
        
        #Gets listing title
        listingTitle = listingBoxes.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'wt-text-caption')
        print("TITLE:", listingTitle.text)

        #Gets price
        listingPrice = listingBoxes.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'currency-value')
        print("ITEM PRICE: $", listingPrice.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
        
        #Gets seller name
        # listingSellerName = listingBoxes.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/main/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[8]/div[2]/div[10]/div[1]/div/div/ol/li/div/div/a[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span[3]')
        # print("SELLER NAME:", listingSellerName.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
        print("---------------")

finally:
    
    driver.quit()

    data = {'Listing URL': listingUrl, 'Listing Thumbnail': listingImg,'Listing Title': listingTitle, 'Listing Price': listingPrice}
    

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')

    df = df.transpose()

    df.to_csv('raw_data.csv')
        
    print('Data has been scrapped and added.')
```

Comment: Please provide more information such as the url, the page source-code, what exactly doesn't work (error-code?) , what you've tried and what exactly the script should do.

Comment: the answer below helped me out! -Thanks for replying though! @kaliiiiiiiii

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code each loop reset the lists `listingUrl`, `listingImg` etc that's why `df` contains only one row of scraped data, corresponding to the last loop executed. If you want to add elements to a list you have to define the list BEFORE the loop and then use the `.append()` method inside the loop.

Then, instead of doing `listingUrl.get_attribute('href')` you will do `listingUrl[-1].get_attribute('href')` where `[-1]` means that you are taking the last element of the list.

```
listingUrl = []

listingImg = []

listingTitle = []

listingPrice = []

for listingBoxes in listingBox:

    #Gets listing url
    listingUrl.append( listingBoxes.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.listing-link') )
    print("LISTING URL:", listingUrl[-1].get_attribute('href'))

    #Gets listing image
    listingImg.append( listingBoxes.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'img.wt-position-absolute') )
    print("IMAGE:", listingImg[-1].get_attribute('src'))
    
    #Gets listing title
    listingTitle.append( listingBoxes.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'wt-text-caption') )
    print("TITLE:", listingTitle[-1].text)

    #Gets price
    listingPrice.append( listingBoxes.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'currency-value') )
    print("ITEM PRICE: $", listingPrice[-1].get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```